# maven compilation errors

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

In my app I have two modules. I need to import classes from one of them to another. for this I  add a dependency to the second like this:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.messagedna-archive.mimeparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>MimeParser</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

and here is the part of the pom.xml of he module which must be imported:

```
  <groupId>com.messagedna-archive.mimeparser</groupId>
  <artifactId>MimeParser</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
```

app is packeged by maven well, but when I'm trying to run it on server i see that:

```
java: package com.messagedna.mimeparser does not exist
```

(this is the package from the first module)
in the class where I call these packages nothing is underlined red.

mvn -install executed for both methods.

how do you think, how this problem can be solved

Comment: try to verify wether MimeParser-1.0.jar is not corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven modules produce artifacts. In your case these are likely jar files.
So eventually you have two jar files which you need to add into the server classpath.
How to do this depends on the server, now you know the general idea.

ps/ "mvn -install" just copies the built artifacts into maven repo, not into your app classpath.